# PigLatin - Removing A Tuple/Field From Relation

Tags: filtering, apache-pig, relation

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so pardon me in advance if this is too lengthy and/or vague.

I have a Pig relation as follows:

```
my_relation = LOAD '/path/to/data' USING PigStorage(',') 
              AS (f1:chararray, f2:chararray, f3:chararray);
```

Now, I wanted to filter out the field 'f3' from the above relation 'my_relation'. I know I could do it like so:

```
my_new_relation = FOREACH my_relation GENERATE my_relation.f1, my_relation.f2;
```

The problem with this method comes when I have a large number of fields/tuples in the 'my_relation' relation. Say, my_relation had 900 fields/tuples, and I wanted all of them but for one. Now, with the above method, I'd have to list out 899 fields/tuples after my 'GENERATE' keyword!

My question: Is there an easy way to filter out a handful of fields/tuples from a relation in PigLatin?

Prior: My prior on Apache Pig and PigLatin in general is very weak (as can be told by the difficulty of this question). I'm still reading through the Pig documentation found [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html).

Thanks for reading this question! Any/all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your syntax is not quite right. If you wanted to just save the fields `f1` and `f2`, you would do it like this:

```
my_new_relation = FOREACH my_relation GENERATE f1, f2;
```

As to your question, you can use a [project-range expression](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#prexp):

```
my_new_relation = FOREACH my_relation GENERATE f1 .. f345, f347 .. f900;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I meant by weak prior -- No idea about correct syntax. I'm still stumbling around. 

I tried the project-range expression trick, and it seems to work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can write your own loader where you can specify which all columns you want to load.

Comment: Can you please link me to some resources?